# Replace parent element with its contents

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to do something similar/same as in this question:
[How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript)

```
<div>
    This is some text here
    <h2>This is more text</h2>
</div>
```

All I want is to remove the H2 tag. The result should be:

```
<div>
    This is some text here
    This is more text
</div>
```

Assume that I have the H2 element already:

```
if (parentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "h2") {
    //now what? I basically want to this: $.replaceWith(parentElement.innerText)
    //just without jQuery
}
```

Comment: get text from h2 element and put it in var. delete the whole h2 and place the text back there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: I voted to close this question. If you have a look at the other answers, they already provide solutions in plain JavaScript. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/176404/218196

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the variable `h2` accurately references the `h2` element you want to act upon, my first thoughts would be:

```
var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0],
    textnode = h2.firstChild;

h2.parentNode.insertBefore(textnode,h2.nextSibling);
h2.parentNode.removeChild(h2);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pm3aM/4/).

To make it slightly more DRY, a function approach could be:

```
function unwrapH2(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var textnode = el.firstChild,
            elParent = el.parentNode;

        elParent.insertBefore(textnode, h2.nextSibling);
        elParent.removeChild(h2);
    }
}

var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];

unwrapH2(h2);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pm3aM/3/).

Adjusted the above in response to Felix Kling's comments (below), and also to use `replaceChild()`:

```
function unwrapH2(el) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var textnode = el.firstChild,
            elParent = el.parentNode;
        elParent.replaceChild(textnode,el);
    }
}

var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];

unwrapH2(h2);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pm3aM/5/).

Comment: `var textnode = h2.firstChild;` is sufficient. I also think you could simply do `h2.parentNode.replaceChild(textnode, h2)`.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! @Felix, of course; thank you! =)

Answer (score 9):

## Use modern JS!

```
const h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
h2.replaceWith(h2.firstChild);
```

To instead replace with all children, use:

```
h2.replaceWith(...h2.childNodes); // or h2.children, if you don't want textNodes
```

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dom-manip-convenience) - 96% Oct '22

Answer (score -1):

First of all, get started on jQuery. It makes your life easier.

In jQuery, do the following:

```
var h2html = $('div h2').html();
$('div h2').remove();
$('div').append(h2html);
```

---

**EDIT:**

The above only works with 1 `div` and 1 `h2` element, which is the last element in the div. It is just a quick example. Below is code that makes your life even more easier:

```
$('div h2').each(function (x, y) {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});​
```

Comment: If the OP wanted to use jQuery, he could just use the code in the linked question. Also, your code is not correct. It replaces the content of each `div` with the content of the first `h2` element. It does preserve the existing text nodes in the `div` elements.

Comment: It does make my life easier, but for one button and 4 lines of Javascript it would be stupid to whip out the whole library.

Comment: @FelixKling Ofcourse this doesn't work for more than 1 div+h2. It is just to show the idea...

Comment: @moontear OK, I had no idea you had no other JS.

Comment: But even with only one (div,h2) it does not provide the desired result. You are replacing the whole content of the `div`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you had `html` instead of `append`. But this also assumes that the `h2` is the last element in the parent. I know you just wanted to provide an example, but the accepted answer in the other is just superior.

Comment: Yes, I agree to that. My code is just simple and quick, for the idea.

Comment: If you make a quick edit, I will remove my downvote. I voted to close the whole question though, since this is really a duplicate of the other question.