# jQuery removing wrapper on elements, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it's a little hack but wondering if it is possible, I have the following markup (example)

```
<div class="homepage-boxes">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What I want to do is remove the

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

wrappers around the span4 containers so it will simply be

```
<div class="homepage-boxes">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

I can't really modify core files on this CMS as will cause issues with upgrades so going for a jQuery approach for a quick fixture until can decide how to action correctly so I know it's likely messy but it will only be for mobile.

Any ideas anyway? I have had a look at .unwrap but did not have much luck with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: try this way https://jsfiddle.net/rwzpry90/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the children elements and then use the [`.unwrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$('.homepage-boxes .row-fluid').children().unwrap();
```

Comment: yep that w ill work but of course that class is used across whole site, is there anyway to target row-fluid just within the homepage-boxes wrapper?

Comment: @James Updated; depending on your needs, you could also use `$('.homepage-boxes .span4').unwrap();`

Comment: cheers dude, i was trying unwrap and also with children but i was doing homepage-boxes .span4 and wasnt working but makes sense, its 4am so heads tired lol thanks for the hand mate!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `unwrap()` method: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```
$('.span4').unwrap();
```