# create button with JS - load data from array

Tags: javascript, html, css, append

I have this code for creating button element in JS file:

```
  var numery = ['A','B','C'];
  var numer = document.createElement("button");
  numer.type = "button";
  numer.value =numery[i];
  numer.className = "class1 class2";
  numer.innerHTML = numery[i];
```

I do not know how to append it (one after another) in HTML, which looks like:

```
    <div class="container_b pull-left" id="container_b">
    <button type="button" class="btn_budynki" id="naglowek_budynkow_zwiniety">Header button</button>
    <div class="btn-group-vertical pull-left hide" role="group" id="grupa_bud">
      <button type="button" class="btn_budynki_top btn_budynki" id="naglowek_budynkow">Another header</button>
<button type="button" class="btn_strzalka btn_strzalka_gora border_top" id="strzalka_gora_bud"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
</button>
      <!-- i want to put created elements as buttons here-->
      <button type="button" class="btn_strzalka btn_strzalka_dol border_top">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If i use appendChild and id of element above: strzalka_gora_bud
then it appends before end tag  of the element.
Can please someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appendChild` is appending the element - which means it goes at the end (before the end tag) of the specified element. So your best option is to create a parent wrapper and fill it with all your buttons. Use an `for` loop for that - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: If by parent wrapper you mean some tag like <span> then it does not work for me, as due to bootstrap it adds css and the elements do not look good

Comment: you can give your span/div a class and use it to override bootstrap's css rules. Also you can use `prepend` instead of `append` - which would put your buttons in the beginning of the parent. You can also specify before or after which element you want to spawn your buttons but I don't think the later serves you better in your case

Comment: do you know how i could replace the wrapper element with the buttons? i know there is option replaceChild, but i do not know how to use it

Comment: you already have a parent to fill up with buttons in your html scheme - #grupa_bud. Now you want to remove it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript - if you really need to. Also if it helped pls accept my answer