# jquery unwrap multiple recursive nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove all the divs that have class 'toBeRemoved' and I am not quite sure how to go about it. I looked into unwrap, but have not been able to get anywhere close to what I am looking for.

Is it possible to easily go from this:

```
<div class="toBeRemoved">
    <div class="toBeRemoved">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="toBeRemoved">
                            <div class="toBeRemoved">
                                <div style="text-align: left;">
                                    <div class="toBeRemoved">
                                        <div class="toBeRemoved">
                                            First node
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="toBeRemoved">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="toBeRemoved">
                            <div class="toBeRemoved">
                                <div style="text-align: left;">
                                    <div class="toBeRemoved">
                                        <div class="toBeRemoved">
                                            Second node.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align: left;">
                    This needs to be kept
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align: left;">
                    This needs to be kept
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is `This needs to be kept` in the original HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace each `.toBeRemoved` element with its immediate children:

```
$('.toBeRemoved').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).children());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/55r29y3w/1)

Answer (score 1):

`.remove()` **Will not work.** As it will remove the children.

```
var cnt = $(".toBeRemoved").contents();
$(".toBeRemoved").replaceWith(cnt);
```

From here. [How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript) 
Duplicate post.

**EDIT should Work Now**

```
$(".toBeRemoved").each( function () {
    var cnt = $(".toBeRemoved").contents();
    $(".toBeRemoved").replaceWith(cnt);
});
```

Comment: The loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Indeed. You did try using `.remove` yes?

Comment: @Juhana I got rid of the loop. Thanks

Comment: Evidently I missed the original post containing the afformentioned loop.

Comment: @Juhana Actually wouldn't `.remove` also remove the elements children??

Comment: Yeah, this solution won't work as it will remove the contents as well.

Comment: I only want to remove the divs containing the class toBeRemoved, I don't want to remove the whole element, please see the bottom part of the question to what the resulting html should be.

Comment: @user3800174 I tried to update your fiddle. It should work now.

Comment: `contents()` won't work, because it includes text nodes, which shouldn't be kept.  Not a duplicate.