# Is there a way to make a html element act as if it isn't there

Tags: css

## Problem

I am using a library that inserts an html element around some content of mine, which is screwing up my layout. I'm looking for a way to tell the layout engine that it should act as if this element's children were just inserted in the place of my element. Is there a way to do this? JavaScript is not available.

### Example

I want this

```html
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner1" />
   <div id="inner2" />
   <div id="i-cant-control-this-but-can-add-css">
      <div id="moreinner1" />
      <!-- .... -->
   </div>
   <div id="inner3" />
</div>
```

to be laid out like

```html
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner1" />
   <div id="inner2" />
   <div id="moreinner1" />
   <!-- .... -->
   <div id="inner3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Pick the element, append it before inner3 and then .remove() the div you can't control

Comment: Try using https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/ `.i-cant-control-this-but-can-add-css { display: contents} `

Comment: Are you able to use JS to do so? If you want to remove the element from the DOM, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript) may be of use if you can?

Comment: @cloned it's display: contents not content

Comment: Display contents is the ideal solution, but bare in mind its limited support before deploying it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

Comment: The correct answer is to use `{ display: contents}`. Note that the question states that I'm only interested in layout, not semantic structure, so one of the linked duplicate questions is erroneous and should be removed (the one mentioning javascript). I don't seem able to do this.

Comment: You can assign `visibility:hidden` or `collapse` to a parent and set `visibility:visible` to the children.