# Remove elements without text and detach children with text only in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some plugin for summernote and after testing I found out that there's a case scenario where it will create structures like this:

```
<span style="text-transform: uppercase">
   <span style="text-transform: lowercase">
       SOME TEXT HERE
   </span>
</span>
```

What can I do to clean up such thing? The idea would be to do a recursion and only leave structures that actually contain text in it.
In the above case would leave only:

```
<span style="text-transform: lowercase">
   SOME TEXT HERE
</span>
```

So there needs to be a detach of children with text.

What's the best solution to achieve this? I thought about using regex but it might not be a good idea.

Found out a quick way to remove totally empty html elements by using:

`$('span:empty', context).remove();`

But doesn't work for these type of case scenarios.

Comment: Duplicated post ? You can take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm actually looking to use unwrap() as well as that post suggests. I'm trying a workaround atm.