# Is it possible to remove an html element and keep your children with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following structure .. I would like to remove `div.son` but keep`div.grandson`, is that possible ?! or changing your `<tag>` would also be a solution .. ex: changing from `<fieldset>` to a `<div>`, remembering that I do not have access to HTML, every change must be done using ** javascript **!

```
<div class="father">
  <fieldset class="son">
    <div class="grandson">Content here</div>
    <div class="grandson">Content here</div>
    <div class="grandson">Content here</div>
    <div class="grandson">Content here</div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I tried to use the `removeChild ()` function of ** javascript **, but it removes the entire element.

Comment: You could save the `grandson` element then remove the `son` and then append the `grandson` to the `father`

Comment: yes, it is possible, you can get the `innerHTML` of `.son` and add it as children of `.father`, then remove `.son`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with vanilla JavaScript by deep cloning the node of *grandson* before removing anything else. and then appending it back to the parent. Of course if you want to place it somewhere else, you need to append needed logic of DOM traversing. (CSS section is only for visual validation of the result)

```js
const grandson = document.querySelector('.grandson');
const father = grandson.closest('.father');
const clonedGrandson = grandson.cloneNode(true);

father.querySelector('.son').remove();
father.appendChild(clonedGrandson);
```

```css
.father {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
 }
 
 .son {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
 }
 
 .grandson {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <fieldset class="son">
    <div class="grandson">
      <p>Save me</p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at this answer, try to use the search bar next time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/170056/10944905

In case you just want to jump all over the answer.

```
var cnt = $(".remove-just-this").contents();
$(".remove-just-this").replaceWith(cnt);
```

Comment: have any example without jQuery?

Comment: There are many answers in the post I linked, you can choose the javascript code you want to be honest.